# What is the name of this 'intermediary' pattern?

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns, microservices

I've got an intermediary java web service application application (built using Spark Java - but that is incidental) that takes an http parameter - from it generates a URL - calls the URL and then returns the result to the original caller.

```
Original Client -> My Application -> Http Web Service Producer
```

This is kind of a MicroServices pattern - but I'm looking for a more specific term. I think it is a 'pipeline', 'solicitor' or a 'mediator'.

My question is: **What is the name of this 'intermediary' pattern?**

Comment: I wouldn't call this a solicitor. That much I could tell you.

Comment: Broker? https://books.google.com/books?id=Y6CmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT271&lpg=PT271&dq=intermediary+pattern+from+client+to+service+producer&source=bl&ots=ay37l6unw6&sig=WHTgbwhJ7hMjsHRWnj0lWHF_3DY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo3qvq1vDNAhVH64MKHYfjDz8Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=intermediary%20pattern%20from%20client%20to%20service%20producer&f=false]

Comment: Sounds like an API gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a API Gateway Pattern, which is commonly used when working with microservices architecture. This pattern hides all services from client allowing client to connect with a API Service. This API Service handle all request while do another stuffs like organize all requisition, for example.

The way this pattern handle requests is a example of Facade Pattern.

I recommend you to read links below to understand how this pattern works properly:
http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/